# How can I get download url from a file of google drive with php?

Tags: php, download, google-drive-api

I´ve followed this guide:

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/php?authuser=1

Now I want to get the dowload link from a file. I am trying to use $file->getDownloadUrl(), but I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile::getDownloadUrl() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Prueba\quickstart.php:84
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Prueba\quickstart.php on line 84
```

This is my code:

```
// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

// Print the names and IDs for up to 10 files.
$optParams = array(
  'pageSize' => 1,
  'fields' => 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)'
);
$results = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);

if (count($results->getFiles()) == 0) {
    print "No files found.\n";
} else {
    print "Files:\n";
    foreach ($results->getFiles() as $file) {

        printf("%s (%s)\n", $file->getName(), $file->getId());
        print($file->getDownloadUrl());
    }
}
```

By the way, client has authorization to download files, because I have defined like this:

```
$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_READONLY);
```

EDIT:

Finally, I have been able to download PDF files with the following code:

```
// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

// Print the names and IDs for up to 3 files.
$optParams = array(
  'pageSize' => 3,
  'fields' => 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)'
);
$results = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);

if (count($results->getFiles()) == 0) {
    print "No files found.\n";
} else {
    print "Files:\n";
    foreach ($results->getFiles() as $file) {

        printf("%s (%s)\n", $file->getName(), $file->getId());
        $fileId = $file->getId();
        $fileToDown = $service->files->get($fileId, array('alt' => 'media'));
        file_put_contents($file->getName(),$fileToDown->getBody());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method getDownloadUrl() not exist. Try:

```
$file->downloadUrl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a method that does not exist.

Check [here](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/php/latest/class-Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile.html) for an overview of the methods available. You want to use the [`getWebContentLink()`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/php/latest/class-Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile.html#_getWebContentLink) method.

In line with the [announcement](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/upcoming-changes-to-the-google-drive-api-and-google-picker-api) *webContentLink* is now the way to get links that download files from Drive.